# Use XSL To Remove Empty Attributes in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I've read through multiple posts and none of the answers have helped solve my issue.

I have an XML document where one of the attributes is optional (Exam ?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="college.xsl" ?>
<College>
  <School>Information Technology</School>
  <Program>Computer Programmer</Program>
  <Course Code="TECH6200">
    <Location>SW202</Location>
    <Day>Tuesday</Day>
    <Duration>8-10am</Duration>
    <Teacher>Devi Ambati</Teacher>
    <Teacher>Darren Puffer</Teacher>
    <Units>4</Units>
    <Coursework>60</Coursework>
    <Exam>40</Exam>
  </Course>
  <Course Code="DBAS6303">
    <Location>H133</Location>
    <Day>Wednesday</Day>
    <Duration>10am-12pm</Duration>
    <Teacher>Kevin D</Teacher>
    <Units>4</Units>
    <Coursework>100</Coursework>
  </Course>
  <Course Code="PROG4208">
    <Location>H166C</Location>
    <Day>Monday</Day>
    <Duration>12-2pm</Duration>
    <Teacher>Kevin D</Teacher>
    <Units>3</Units>
    <Coursework>100</Coursework>
  </Course>
</College>
```

Then I have my XSL document. I want to switch this to not even display `Exam %:` if there is no `<Exam></Exam>` tag in the `<Course></Course>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <b>School:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="College/School"/><br/>
    <b>Program:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="College/Program"/><br/><br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="College/Course">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Code"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <p>
          <b>Location:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Location"/><br/>
          <b>Day:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Day"/><br/>
          <b>Duration:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Duration"/><br/>
          <xsl:for-each select="Teacher">
            <b>Teacher:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <b>Units:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Units"/><br/>
          <b>Course Work %:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Coursework"/><br/>
          <b>Exam %:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Exam"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the usage of the Exam value in a test for the presence of it:

```
...
<xsl:if test="Exam">
  <b>Exam %:</b>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="Exam"/>
</xsl:if>
...
```

Comment: Why would you use the `string` function instead of just saying `test="Exam"`?

Comment: @David for some reason I never thought to try that. Thanks for teaching me something new. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, and is super simple.

Comment: `test="string(Exam)"` would check that the Exam element exists, and has non-empty content. `test="Exam"` only checks that it exists.